# Travis project failing but not on own server

Tags: php, phpunit, travis-ci

I'm pulling my hair out trying to fix the issues in my Travis CI build failling. I can't seem to find out why it's working locally (probably a configuration setting) but doesn't work on Travis CI.

My project is located at https://travis-ci.org/crazycodr/data-grouper on Travis CI and the source is at https://github.com/crazycodr/data-grouper.

I have several issues in my build all related to /src/CrazyCodr/Data/Grouper/GroupResult.php:447

But i don't see anything passed by reference over there so it's either a configuration issues or something i just don't get!

Further more, if one could find out why i only have 65/68 tests being run... I really don't get why i'm having this too, i check all my test files and there are no test without an assertion or an @exceptedException so i'm a bit clueless as to what is hapenning there... Note i have the 65/68 problem on both servers but the Reference error in the build is only on Travis CI.

Comment: ok never mind the 65/68, i finaly understood that it simply means that on that line, there are 65/68 tests run and the next line there are ... more dots meaning the last 3 tests are run there, so now, only the problem with the reference in important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG, thanks to "http://geoffray.be/blog/php/only-variables-should-be-passed-by-reference", i found the solution to my error...

I was using

```
//Return the Group
return reset(array_filter($this->groups, function($a)use($value){ return $a->getGroupValue() === $value; }));
```

And it was reset() that was being STRICT with me on Travis CI that i should pass a variable and not a temporary variable, so i changed it to the more ugly form of

```
$result = array_filter($this->groups, function($a)use($value){ return $a->getGroupValue() === $value; });
return reset($result);
```

The only thing left is to find out why

```
error_reporting = E_ALL
```

Doesn't include E_STRICT on Site5.com

Comment: E_STRICT became part of E_ALL only in PHP 5.4.0